# Dynamic sql query - number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a dynamic query according to the information it gets.

When $query2 is for example:  'type' => 'PvP', 'online' => 'Premium'

And $query is: SELECT * FROM dispserveur WHERE type = :type AND online = :online

This is working,

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("$query");
$req->execute(array('type' => 'PvP', 'online' => 'Premium'));
```

But when i use the $query2 variable in the execute, it's not working.

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("$query"); //C
$req->execute(array($query2));
```

I get the same error each time.

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

This is the code,

```
unset($sql);
unset($sql2);

if (isset($type2) AND $type2 != "all") {
$sql[] = " type = :type ";
$sql2[] = " 'type' => '$type2'";

}

if (isset($online2) AND $online2 != "all") {
$sql[] = " online = :online ";
$sql2[] = " 'online' => '$online2'";

}
if (isset($version2) AND $version2 != "all") {
$sql[] = " version LIKE :version ";
$sql2[] = " 'version' => %$version2%";

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM dispserveur";

if (!empty($sql)) {
$query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql);
}
if (!empty($sql2)) {
$query2 = implode(', ', $sql2); 
}

echo $query;
echo "<br />";
echo $query2;

$req = $bdd->prepare("$query"); //C
$req->execute(array($query2));
while ($red = $req->fetch())
{echo "$red[ip]<br />";}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `execute()` should be an associative array whose keys match that `:paramName`. Instead, you're using `$query2` which is just a string.  That's why your code isn't working.

Change:

```
$sql2[] = " 'type' => '$type2'";
$sql2[] = " 'online' => '$online2'";
$sql2[] = " 'version' => %$version2%";
```

to:

```
$sql2['type']=$type2;
$sql2['online']=>$online2;
$sql2['version']=>"%$version2%";
```

And later, change

```
$req->execute(array($query2));
```

to

```
$req->execute($sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The beetlejuice's method is correct but it's not

> $req->execute(array($query2));
>
> to
>
> $req->execute(array($sql2));

but

```
$req->execute(array($query2));

to

$req->execute($sql2);
```

Thank you for your quick answer :)